# GVR Audio Engine for iOS crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb, google-vr-sdk, resonance-audio

I'm trying to run a program using the Google Resonance Audio SDK for iOS, but every time I try to initialize the GVRAudioEngine, the application crashes and this error appears in XCode:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, 
      address=0xffffffffffffffe8)
```

Does anyone have experience running Google Resonance Audio on iPhone?

Specifically, I'm trying to run the program from this tutorial, [Treasure Hunt Demo](https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/develop/ios/getting-started), the example tutorial provided by Google, but using Xcode 10.0 and iOS 11 or 12, I get the error message above while following the directions.

Comment: Check out my answer. It may help. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this podfile

```
target 'TreasureHunt' do
  pod 'GVRKit' , '1.140.0'
  pod 'GVRAudioSDK' , '1.140.0'
end
```

And run `pod update`

This crash could be caused when there is a version mismatch between `GVRSDK` and `GVRAudioSDK`([source](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/329)).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the guid step by step and it will work:

- Clone [this repo](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk)
- In a Terminal window, navigate to the Samples/TreasureHunt folder, and install the CocoaPod dependencies by running this command: `pod install`
- optionally run `pod update` to insure you have the latest version
- In Xcode, open the TreasureHunt **workspace** (Samples/TreasureHunt/TreasureHunt.xcworkspace), and click Run.

Project successfully run with these pods works on Xcode 10:

```
GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
GVRAudioSDK (1.140.0)
GVRKit (1.140.0)
GVRSDK (1.140.0)
GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)
```

**Troubleshooting**:

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means something is not accessible. Maybe it's an object that has been deallocated earlier, or some retain loop. you must investigate it from the stack trace. The following may help:

- open **edit scheme** ( cmd + < )
- check **zombie objects**
- run project

It will tell you if a message was sent to a zombie and you can trace it

Comment: Also, set an exception breakpoint. You may get a break when the error happens, where the exception gets passed up.